# While implementing StartApp ads , i am getting StartApp ads Error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, ads, startapp

The error is given below: _

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Enum.ordinal()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                   at com.startapp.android.publish.cache.g.i(StartAppSDK:277)
>                                                                                   at com.startapp.android.publish.cache.g.j(StartAppSDK:374)
>                                                                                   at com.startapp.android.publish.cache.g$1.onFailedToReceiveAd(StartAppSDK:356)
>                                                                                   at com.startapp.android.publish.cache.i$3$1.run(StartAppSDK:241)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6237)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Earlier it was working fine, but now this error is coming.

`onCreate` method I am calling this:

```
// StartAppSDK.init(this, "210075679", true);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
StartAppSDK.init(MainActivity.this, "210075679", true);
```

Comment: show your complete activity code

Comment: whenever I comment //  StartAppSDK.init(MainActivity.this, "210075679", true);    it works fine ,there is no app crash.

Comment: show me your menifiest file

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer after adding this in Progaurd rules

```
-keep class com.startapp.** {*;}
-keepattributes Exceptions, InnerClasses, Signature, Deprecated, 
SourceFile,LineNumberTable, *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod
-dontwarn android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
```

Comment: great  keep it up